# Hide folder with Microsoft Graph REST API

Tags: rest, api, graph, office365, exchange-server

Is it possible to use the Microsoft Graph REST API to hide a folder that is a child of the inbox for all users?

Answer (score 0):

Technically its possible using

```
    {
    "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
        {
            "id":"boolean 0x10f4",
            "value":"true"
        }
    ]
    }
```

which is equivalent to what it being done in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-hidden-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange

The problem with this is even through it will work it will firstly return an error because once you hide a folder in then become inaccessible using the Graph and you won't be able to use that API again to access or unhide the folder. You may be better to look at creating a normal folder under the Non_IPM_Subtree (/MailFolders('root')) if you really need a hidden folder in the mailbox and you need to be able to access it with the Graph after that.